# Delphi XE3: TWebUpdate by TMS software: does not replace main exe-file

Tags: delphi, tms

to update my applications I'm using TWebUpdate by TMS software:

```
WebUpdate1.URL:='http://myserver.com/update.inf';
if WebUpdate1.NewVersionAvailable then
begin
case Application.MessageBox(PChar('The new version '+WebUpdate1.NewVersionInfo+' is available! Update it?'), 
'Updates Are Available', MB_YESNO + MB_ICONQUESTION) of
  IDYES:
    begin
     SetCurrentDir(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName));
     WebUpdate1.DoUpdate;
     WebUpdate1.DoRestart;
    end;
  IDNO:
    begin
      Application.Terminate;
    end;
end;
```

Here is the update.info file:

```
[update]
newversion=2.1.0.37
localversion=client_app.exe
[files]
count=1
[file1]
url=http://myserver.com/client_app.exe
newversion=2.1.0.37
localversion=client_app.exe
mandatory=1
[application]
appupdate=1
silentrestart=1
appname=client_app.exe
appcomps=client_app.ex_
```

Actually, the update works fine (the exe-file is downloaded and the application is restarted), but the exe-file is not replaced by downloaded file. Where may be a problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you asked the vendor? TMS has pretty responsive support and has user forums that are actively monitored by staff.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Yes, yesterday. Has not yet received a response.

Comment: It's easter. And now it's the weekend. You may need to be patient.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I have no weekends ;) So I need an urgent solution to this issue.

Comment: And I need a pony. The [faq](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/wupdate.asp?s=faq) says that you debug problems by setting "TWebUpdate.Logging = true" what does the log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the downloaded file MUST be compressed as cab-file. That is:

```
[update]
newversion=2.1.0.37
localversion=client_app.exe
[files]
count=1
[file1]
url=http://myserver.com/client_app.ex_
newversion=2.1.0.37
localversion=client_app.exe
mandatory=1
[application]
appupdate=1
silentrestart=1
appname=client_app.exe
appcomps=client_app.ex_
```

And of course:

```
WebUpdate1.ExtractCAB:=True;
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, Mr. Red October.  I have thought about using the TWebUpdate component myself, but it has been around for quite a while and I did not know whether it was just some simple copy program or what.  Your question and answer are right on point for me.  I will check out the component.

Comment: Where is the cab file in this example? The only difference I see is that the URL is different. It now points to what I assume is a compressed file instead of the regular EXE. It makes sense that this would work since you tell it that the application component is a .ex_ file, but you previously told it to download a .exe file.